# Приложение не видит USB-OTG

Tags: java, android, usb

Проблема - Как заставить мои приложения увидеть USB флешки-мышки? (Вопрос НЕ о подключении к компьютеру)

Далее я опишу подробно (можно всё пропустить кроме последнего абзаца), но кратко: 99% вероятности - суть проблемы в запрете доступа сторонних приложений к USB-OTG в Android 4. KitKat (я не буду описывать почему я так уверен в программах которые и с плей маркета и мои, и чужие, OTG кабеле и др.)

Подробно: Телефон Meizu MX4 Pro (Android 4.4.4, API 19) видит вообще все USB 
флешки-мышки но только штатным проводником. Все сторонние приложения (кроме ES File) заявляют об отсутствии OTG. И не было бы проблемы если бы и не мои программы которые тоже не видят внешних устройств! Вон оно зло в чистом виде! После очень долгого перебора сторонних программ, лазанья по базару и выпрашивая с собачьими глазами попробовать разные OTG переходники, ослабленный после операции споткнулся, упал и разбил экран =(. После сайтов и форумов пришел к выводу, что причина в ... Android 4. Где были намеренно произведены сложности в доступе сторонним программам к внешним носителям!

Прописи в манифесте не увенчались успехом, ну тогда я скачал и декомпилировал готовый ES File .apk (менеджер который смог увидеть USB флешки), зашел в её огромный манифест, далее лишь его часть:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name=".PERMISSION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" /> 
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> 
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
</intent-filter>
...
<activity 
android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESUsePromptActivity" 
android:launchMode="singleTop" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />


<activity android:theme="@style/ES.Base.Theme.NoActionBar" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.UsbMonitorActivity" 
android:enabled="true" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

<intent-filter> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> 
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />


И файл-фильтр указанный в манифесте:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<usb-device class="8" />
</resources>
```

Но моя сверх гениальная =) идея не помогла, так что же делать? Естественно, я знаю о разрешениях приложения в телефоне. Опять напомню суть проблемы - заставить ИМЕННО МОИ приложения увидеть USB устройства типа флешки и мышки (подключение к компьютеру НЕ интересует). Сторонние я скачивал только что бы узнать о решении проблемы. Может манифест я не правильно оформил, или что ещё нужно добавить куда то? А может есть ещё какое-то секретное разрешение в настройках телефона? Нельзя упомянуть, что у меня телефон практически не поддерживает секретные коды типа *#*#12345#*#*, я уже пробовал. Прошу помощи, всё что мог делал сам, теперь я в тупике. Буду очень рад любому предположению.

Comment: pavlofff, я понял и учту.

Comment: видимо нужно ознакомится с [этой документацией](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)

Comment: смотрите так же [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489487/7566397)

Comment: Так же взгляните на [эту документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

Comment: рад, что ссылки оказались вам полезны. Сам я не работал с usb-otg поэтому слабо представляю, что именно решило вашу проблему и не могу дать полноценный ответ на ваш вопрос. Лучше вы сами напишите ответ (ответить на собственный вопрос), который решил вашу проблему

Comment: pavlofff, пока ещё ничего не получается, да и я два месяца "отроду", глупый, но я очень рад, что появилась надежда. Если найду ответ, то обязательно напишу, не хочу, что бы люди мучились из-за того, что AS сделали таким ... пусть назовём это - "сложным".

Comment: хочу повторить, что Android Studio всего лишь IDE,  инструмент для набора кода и сборки приложения, к вашим проблемам она не имеет никакого отношения. Это то же самое что говорить, когда смотришь убогую экранку на 4K телевизоре: "И зачем они сделали этот телевизор с таким плохим качеством изображения". Нужно различать API системы, под которую разрабатываешь приложение и инструменты, с помощью которых это делаешь. Точно такие же проблемы будут, если вы будете разрабатывать свое приложение в IDE Eclipse, к примеру. "Сложная"  - система доступа к файлам в Android, но думаю и на это были причины.